# ¿Otros elementos toman el evento click y no el que lo tiene?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tomando un elemento con JavaScript

```
<div class="game-container" id="paper">
   <span class="game__paper" >
     <span class="game__box-shadow">
         <img src="../images/icon-paper.svg" alt="Paper">
     </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

```
const paperId = document.getElementById('paper');

function choiceGun(event) {

    console.log(event);
    paper = event.target.id;
    console.log(rock);

  }

paperId.addEventListener('click', choiceGun);
```

y estoy escuchando  el evento click en el `div (game-container)` que sería el container de todo el bloque, pero le doy click y el `event` que sale en la consola, sale con el elemento `game__paper` o  `gamebox-shadow` o con el elemento `game__container` y eso depende de que parte de del elemento `game__container` le de click.

Yo necesito que cuando le de click a `game__paper` solo seleccione ese elemento.

Comment: Saludos. Mmmm, de lo poco que se te comento; no pusiste el elemento cuyo `ìd` es `rock` por consiguiente no se sabe; asi como tampoco como asignas (por código o directamente en un evento de elemento) la función `choiceGun`desde donde se dispara. Si lo pones a un `div` sus hijos igual lo lanzan, salvo valides por ejemplo que se evalue el `id` y si corresponde al del `div` se ejecute completo.

Comment: Ya formule mejor la preguntas, eso espero.

Comment: pues añade el evento click en el elemento con la clase `game__paper` en vez de `paper`

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- No veo la necesidad o utilidad de que un span sea contenedor de otro span que a su vez contiene una imagen
- En ese sentido y tal vez para organizar mejor el código sería:

  - un solo span que envuelva a la imagen
- Sería un tanto difícil aplicar un click sobre dicho elemento (*el span*) por que su ancho estará delimitado por el contenido que en ella exista
- En ese sentido tal vez un elemento de bloque sea una mejor opción ya que de manera inicial ocupa todo el ancho disponible, lo cual te daría opción o espacio para el evento deseado
- Si deseamos seguir por la línea del span, entonces al borde deberás darle un ancho para diferenciarlo de su contenido, que en este caso es la imagen

Propuesta:

```html
    <style>
      .game-container {
        border: 10px solid crimson;
        padding: 40px;
      }
      .elemento-no {
        border: 1px solid teal;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .game__paper {
        border: 10px solid ;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      p.game__paper {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="game-container" id="paper">
       <span class="game__paper" >
             <img src="../images/icon-paper.svg" alt="Paper">
       </span>
       <span class="game__paper" >
             <img src="../images/icon-paper.svg" alt="Paper">
       </span>
       <p class="game__paper" >
             <img src="../images/icon-paper.svg" alt="Paper">
       </p>
       <p class="elemento-no">
         Hola Mundo
       </p>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
      let divContenedor = document.getElementById('paper');
      
      divContenedor.addEventListener('click', (evento) => {
        (evento.target.className != 'game__paper') 
          ? (console.log('Aqui el click no'))
          : (console.log('Aqui el click si'))
      });
    </script>
```

Tal vez en este sentido te convenga mas apuntar a la imagen mediante una clase, pues ya que le insertes contenido multimedia tendrás todo ese espacio para capturar el evento click.

Otra propuesta:

```html
    <style>
      .game-container {
        border: 10px solid crimson;
        padding: 40px;
      }
      .elemento-no {
        border: 1px solid teal;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .game__paper {
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="game-container" id="paper">
       <span class="game__paper" >
             <img class="game__paper-image" src="../images/icon-paper.svg" alt="Paper">
       </span>
       <span class="game__paper" >
             <img class="game__paper-image" src="../images/icon-paper.svg" alt="Paper">
       </span>
       <p class="elemento-no">
         Hola Mundo
       </p>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
      let divContenedor = document.getElementById('paper');
      
      divContenedor.addEventListener('click', (evento) => {
        (evento.target.className != 'game__paper-image') 
          ? (console.log('Aqui el click no'))
          : (console.log('Aqui el click si'))
      });
    </script>
```

**Lecturas recomendadas**

- [Elementos en línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea)
- [Elementos en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)
- [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target)